# How can I make the results of a csv file-to-multidimensional array available globally?

Tags: node.js

If I have a global array:

```
    var people = [];
```

And I have the following function:

```
function readFile() {
     var IN = require('ya-csv');
     var filePath = 'data.csv';
     var reader = IN.createCsvFileReader(filePath, {
          'separator': ','
     });
     reader.on('data', function(item) {
          people.push(item);
     });
}
```

The people array only seems scoped inside reader.on. How can I use the people array globally?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly right if the `people` variable is declared outside the `readFile` function, which seems to be the case.

I guess that your problem is something like this:

```
var people = [];

function readFile() {
  var IN = require('ya-csv');
  var filePath = 'data.csv';
  var reader = IN.createCsvFileReader(filePath, {
    separator: ',' // quotes around property name are optional
  });
  reader.on('data', function(item) {
    people.push(item);
  });
}

readFile();
console.log(people); // <- people is empty
```

This behaviour is absolutely normal. As ya-csv process incoming data asynchronously, you have to wait for processing to be finished.

That's the purpose of the `end` event, triggered by CsvReader when it has finished (unfortunately not documented on [ya-csv documentation](https://github.com/koles/ya-csv))

Refactoring like this will work better:

```
// make filePath a parameter, and use a callback function
function readFile(filePath, callback) {
  // make people scoped to readFile()
  var people = [];
  var IN = require('ya-csv');
  var reader = IN.createCsvFileReader(filePath, {
    separator: ',' // quotes around property name are optional
  });

  // data is emitted for each processed line
  reader.on('data', function(item) {
    // closure magic: people is accessible because current function is nested into readFile()
    people.push(item);
  });

  // end event
  reader.on('end', function() {
    // return results to caller, simply by invoking the callback.
    // by convention, first argument is an error, which is null it no problem occured
    callback(null, people);
  });

  // error handling
  reader.on('error', function(err) {
    // stop listening on events, to avoid continuing queuing data
    reader.removeAllListeners();
    // report to caller the error.
    callback(err);
  }
}

readFile('data.csv', function(err, results) {
  if (err) {
    // error handling
    return ...
  }
  // nominal case: use results that contains peoples !
  console.dir(results);
});
```

Please ask question with comments if something is not clear.

**== EDIT ==**

Alternatively, you can use a variable outside `readFile()`

```
// notice: people is declared outside readFile
var people = []

// make filePath a parameter, and use a callback function
function readFile(filePath, callback) {
  var IN = require('ya-csv');
  var reader = IN.createCsvFileReader(filePath, {
    separator: ',' // quotes around property name are optional
  });

  // data is emitted for each processed line
  reader.on('data', function(item) {
    // closure magic: people is accessible because current function is nested into readFile()
    people.push(item);
  });

  // end event: directly invoke callback
  reader.on('end', callback);

  // error handling
  reader.on('error', function(err) {
    // stop listening on events, to avoid continuing queuing data
    reader.removeAllListeners();
    // report to caller the error.
    callback(err);
  }
}

readFile('data.csv', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    // error handling
    return ...
  }
  // you cannot use people before here, because you have no garantie that read process is finished.
  console.dir(people);
});
```

The drawback of this code is that calling `readFile()` multiple times will enqueue in the same variable, which is not modular nor reliable.

Comment: So there is no way to export results to be used outside of readFile() function call?